# Handling that annoying "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: getChars (5 ... 0) has end before start" bug

Tags: android, android-widget

I get about 50 of these coming from my users each day.

I realise that this is a Motorola Droid bug - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5164

Is there anyway I can catch this error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception seems to be triggered deep within `TextView`, so unless you subclass `TextView` or the variants you use and catch that exception in a protected method, there's not much you can do.